# Inserting sections in UITableView causes row error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView I'm updating with a plist from my servers. I would like to insert and delete the sections in the tableview with the following methods:

```
[global.tableVC.tableViewOutlet insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[global.tableVC.tableViewOutlet deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

Problem is that the different sections I have, also have a lot of rows, so I always get this error when I update the tableview:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070
2013-05-11 13:16:39.946 uninkd[19619:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 3.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Now, I know what it is telling me here, that all of the sudden section 3 has 0 rows instead of 1, but I don't really know how to deal with it.

Do I have to loop through all the section, check if the section has rows and then... delete those rows and insert them below? Move them?

This is my full code for updating the tableview:

```
[global.tableVC.tableViewOutlet beginUpdates];

// Update data
NSString *manifestPlistPath = [global.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Manifest.plist"];
[plist writeToFile:manifestPlistPath atomically:YES];

// Insert new section
[global.tableVC.tableViewOutlet insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

[global.tableVC.tableViewOutlet endUpdates];
```

**Update With Issues and cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
-(NSMutableArray *)issues{
    // 1. Initiate issues array
    _issues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // 2. Define and set magazine and foreword
    NSString *magazinePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Magazine" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSString *forewordPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Foreword" ofType:@"plist"];

    // 3. If we have any issues, then reset the magazine and foreword path
    if (kLibrary.issues.count) {
        // A. Get the last issue
        NKIssue *lastIssue = [kLibrary.issues lastObject];

        // B. Redefine the magazine and foreword path
        magazinePath = [[lastIssue.contentURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Magazine.plist"];
        forewordPath = [[lastIssue.contentURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Foreword.plist"];
    }

    // 5. If file exists at that path, then set the manifestplistdic
    if ([self manifest].count){
        // B. Add the individual issues to the issues global
        for (NSMutableDictionary __strong *issue in [self manifest]){
            NSString *issueName = [[issue objectForKey:@"Issue"] objectForKey:@"Name"];
            NKIssue *libraryIssue = [kLibrary issueWithName:issueName];
            if (libraryIssue) {
                NSString *issuePath = [[libraryIssue.contentURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Issue.plist"];
                issue = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:issuePath];
            }

            [_issues addObject:issue];
        }
    }

    // 6. Add the magazine and foreword
    [_issues insertObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:magazinePath] atIndex:0];
    [_issues addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:forewordPath]];

    // 7. Return the array
    return _issues;
}


- (DTAttributedTextCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return (DTAttributedTextCell *)[self tableView:tableView preparedCellForIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (DTAttributedTextCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView preparedCellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // 1. Get cell cache if cell has already been created
    CustomCellView *cell = [global rowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // 2. Create cell if it doesn't exist
    if (!cell){
        // A. Define cell string (for first row in buy section
        NSString *cellString = @"";

        // C. If we have articles, then reset cell string
        if([global sectionAtSection:indexPath.section].bought){
            // A. Find the right issue and article
            NSDictionary *article = [global articleAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            // B. Set the cell string and put it into an attributed string
            cellString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [article objectForKey:@"Headline"], [article objectForKey:@"Byline"], [article objectForKey:@"Lead"]];
        }

        // D. Create the cell from the cell identifier
        cell = [[CustomCellView alloc] initWithIndexPath:indexPath title:cellString];

        // E. Cache the cell, if there is a cache
        [_rowCache setObject:cell forKey:[global cellKeyFromIndexPath:indexPath]];
    }

    // 3. Return the cell
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're not updating the data model that backs your table view, is that possible?

Comment: No, I'm doing that as one of the first things - [plist writeToFile:manifestPlistPath atomically:YES] - the plist is my data model. It is complaining that before there where 1 row in the section, but now there's 0, which is true, because I've inserted a seciton at the top and therefore all the other sections have been pushed down. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Writing it to a file is one thing, but a file is only a "raw" data model. I assume this file is loaded into an NSArray or NSDictionary at some point and that is your *actual* data source. However, this array or dictionary doesn't get updated when you write the file. You need to  make the changes to the array/dictionary as well.

Comment: Ok. In my case, the file is basically the data. UITableViewController grabs the data from a method called "issues", which grabs the data from the file. Do you need to call "reloadData" when you do beginUpdates and endUpdates?

Comment: No, you don't need to call `reloadData`. Please edit your post with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `issues`, that will give us a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: There you go. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't see a call to `issues` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. (I wouldn't recommend doing that either, btw.) This means that your backing array `global` will be out of sync with the plist after you write to manifestPlistPath. You have to update global when you update your file.

Comment: Think you are on the right path. I'm looking into it and will update (hopefully shortly). Thanks.